# Can't return a dict for a method Python

Tags: python, dictionary, oop, return-value

I am using Python 3.8.3 on Windows, I'm very new at OOP.

I am working on some trello stuff for work and I wanted to create a trello object so I can call them across the various functions. I had this working previously under FP but since converting it over it isn't working as expected for me.

What I'm trying to do is get a `dict` back from the method to assign to a variable, however when I do a test and print the result, this is what I get:

`<function TrelloInfo.members at 0x00000...>`

Please see below for code:

```
class TrelloInfo():
    
    def __init__(self):
    
        # account key and token
        self.query = {
        'key': 'key',
        'token': 'token'
        }

    def cards(self):
        # get card info
        urlcards = "cardurl"

        responsecards = requests.request(
        "GET",
        urlcards,
        params=self.query
        )

        cleanedupcards = json.loads(responsecards.text)

        return cleanedupcards

    def members(self):

        # get member info
        urlmembers = "memberurl"

        responsemembers = requests.request(
        "GET",
        urlmembers,
        params=self.query
        )

        cleanedupmembers = json.loads(responsemembers.text)

        return cleanedupmembers

    def lists(self):
        # get lists in the board
        urllists = "listsurl"

        responselists = requests.request(
        "GET",
        urllists,
        params=self.query
        )

        cleaneduplists = json.loads(responselists.text)

        return cleaneduplists

    def labels(self):
        # get label info
        urllabels = "labelsurl"

        responselabels = requests.request(
        "GET",
        urllabels,
        params=self.query
        )

        cleaneduplabels = json.loads(responselabels.text)

        return cleaneduplabels
    
test = TrelloInfo

cards = test.cards
members = test.members

print(members)
```

I feel like I'm missing something really small but I haven't been able to find an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to create an instance of your class, rather than assigning the class itself to a variable, which basically just creates an alias for that class:

```
test = TrelloInfo()
```

Then, you'll want to invoke the methods of that instance:

```
cards = test.cards()
members = test.members()
```

Answer (score 3):

Your problem here is that your actually setting `members` to be a pointer to the class method members without executing it.

You have to add `()` to execute it:

```py
test = TrelloInfo()

cards = test.cards()
members = test.members()
```

Comment: wait until you send stuff like that for review when your getting paid for it :P

Comment: #thatsthedream... slowly working on my skills to be able to do this full time.